# Adding More Than One Javascript Declaration to Joomla Module On Same Page

Tags: javascript, joomla, module

I'm building out a module that needs to initiate a slider. Something similar to this:

```
jQuery('#slider').anythingSlider();
```

I can do that as long as I only have one module on the page, but if I add more than one module to the page, it will only add the last script declaration. The reason I need to cal this more than once is to have more than one slider on the same page, each with their own options (there's a plethora of options).

I've tried `scriptDeclaration` and I've even tried echoing the script to see if it would allow it to be echoed.

I'm am building on Joomla 1.7.3. This is isn't the first time I've had this problem, but this is the first time it's absolutely necessary to get this working correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things you could do:

**1) use a class declaration to initialise your slider**

```
jQuery('.slider').anythingSlider();
```

Now, all containers with the "slider"-class will be processed by the plugin.

**2) just use different id's for your html containers.**

Im not sure, what the exact html markup is, that your plugin requires, but something like this should work.

In your default.php (template):

```
 <div id="module_<?php echo $module->id; ?>">
  // your html stuff
 </div>

// now add the jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#module_<?php echo $module->id; ?>').anythingSlider();
</script>
```

The second option would be better, since it would allow you to use different configurations for wach slider. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have it set up like that already. The problem is that Joomla only outputs 1 script declaration. So I could have 30 modules on 1 page with different IDs or classes, but Joomla would only initiate the last module to be loaded (or the one with the highest ID, I'm not sure which). So I can only set the options for 1 slider, not any of the rest. I'm trying to figure out how to tell Joomla to print a script declaration for each module of the same type (even if it has to access functions from a component).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Joomla only outputs 1 script declaration"?  I am not quite sure what you mean by that..

Comment: When building a module I have a php variable with the javascript output. I use the Joomla function `addScriptDeclaration($var)` to insert the javascript into the head of the document. That's how I initiate the slider. This should be done for each and every module, but Joomla will only output one of the `addScriptDeclaration($var)` even if I have 30 of the same modules on the page (I need it to produce that code for each and every module but it won't even though that code is created within the module itself). I hope that explains it clear enough :). Thanks for helping!

Comment: well, you could just get rid of the addScriptDeclaration stuff and just include the javascript in your template, as in my example...

Comment: I had a helper file that I was using to print the scripts (I tried what you were using in your second example within that helper file) but it wouldn't work. It wasn't until I placed the `addScriptDeclaration` in the default.php that it started working. I'm still not sure why it does that, but I'm glad it's fixed. Thank you so much!